# Free expansion of a harmonic trapped atoms

Tags: atomic-physics, bose-einstein-condensate

I read the book by Bose-Eistein condensation in dilute gas by C. J. Pethick, H. Smith. I met a question in page 31 (chapter 2,3,1).

Thereof, they said that the distribution function of harmonic trapped atoms in equilibrium is $f_p(
\vec{r})=\exp{(\mu/kT)}\exp{[-\Big(p^2/2m+\frac{1}{2}m\omega_x^2x^2+\frac{1}{2}m\omega_y^2y^2+\frac{1}{2}m\omega_z^2z^2\Big)/kT]}.$ Then assume we turn off the trap at t=0 the distribution function at later time t is:

$$
f_p(\vec{r},t)=\exp{(\mu/kT)}\exp{[-\Big(p^2/2m+\frac{1}{2}m\omega_x^2(x-\frac{p_xt}{m})^2+\frac{1}{2}m\omega_y^2(y-\frac{p_yt}{m})^2+\frac{1}{2}m\omega_z^2(z-\frac{p_zt}{m})^2\Big)/kT]}
$$

However, when the trap is turned off, there should be only one term in the exponent of exponential function: $\frac{p^2}{2m}.$ How does the potential term live when we consider case of free expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free expansion only determines the dynamics. Your setting is purely classical, the phase space pdf's evolution is governed by the Liouville equation (deterministic version of the master equation):
$$
\partial_t\rho+\{\rho,H\} = 0
$$
with the free space Hamiltonian:
$$
H = \frac{p^2}{2m}
$$
As always, you need to specify the initial condition, $\rho(t=0)$. This is given by the Boltzman distribution of the harmonic oscillator. It is justified by a thermalisation of the atoms in the trap. Once you take away the trap, the pdf stays in this Boltzman distribution, which is not the one corresponding to the new Hamiltonian, hence the time evolution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank for your comment